# Is there any way to give factory function(s) to `typing.NamedTuple` subclasses?

Tags: python-3.x, python-typing

Note: I had done this with Python 3.6.7, but the documentation did not change for `NamedTuple` there, so I doubt if it would change there.

So I am looking at the [NamedTuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple) class from the typing package and I wonder if there is a way to add a mutable default value to it. The first attempt is see if I can use the `_make` classmethod to my advantage, but then I discovered that the class checked against overriding `__new__`.

(Recap: if you put `[]` into the default value, you end up with every object sharing the same list. This is true for both the old `collections.namedtuple` and the new `typing.NamedTuple`. This is why the `collections.defaultdict` class has a `default_factory` argument in the constructor.)

```py
>>> from typing import NamedTuple, List
>>> class Person(NamedTuple):
...   name: str
...   children: List['Person']
...   def __new__(self, name: str, children: List['Person'] = None):
...     return Person._make(name, children if children is not None else [])
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/typing.py", line 2163, in __new__
    raise AttributeError("Cannot overwrite NamedTuple attribute " + key)
AttributeError: Cannot overwrite NamedTuple attribute __new__
>>>
```

I continued to puzzle at how to sneak a list into the stubborn `__new__`, but then it started not making sense in general.

```
>>> class Person(NamedTuple):
...   name: str
...   children: List['Person'] = None
... 
>>> 
>>> def new_new(name: str, children: List[Person] = None) -> Person:
...   return Person(name, [] if children is None else children)
... 
>>> old_new = Person.__new__
>>> def new_new(name: str, children: List[Person] = None) -> Person:
...   return old_new(name, [] if children is None else children)
... 
>>> Person.__new__ = new_new
>>> 
>>> Person('John')
Person(name='John', children=None)
>>> Person.__new__
<function new_new at 0x7f776b2b2e18>
>>> new_new('John')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in new_new
  File "<string>", line 14, in __new__
TypeError: tuple.__new__(X): X is not a type object (str)
>>> new_new(Person, 'John')
Person(name='John', children=None)
>>>
```

So, how should this be done? I am used to doing that same thing for `collections.namedtuple` classes, and this is mostly curiosity.

In all practicality, I should probably do this:

```
class Person(NamedTuple):
  name: str
  children: List['Person'] = None

  @classmethod
  def create(cls, name, children=None):
    return cls(name, [] if children is None else children)
```

Comment: While it does not strictly answer your question, the [``attrs`` package](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/) supports both type-checking and default arguments factories as desired. It will not create a NamedTuple, though.

Comment: Well @MisterMiyagi every day you learn of a new Python package. This is probably what I will give a good hard look into then try to use everywhere, but like you've said, not the answer to this question. Although, "it is not intended to be powerful" is also a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: Note that the behaviour of ``Person.__new__ = new_new`` is consistent. Calling ``Person(*args)`` is equivalent to ``Person.__new__(Person, *args)``, not ``Person.__new__(*args)``. ``__new__`` is invoked like a ``classmethod`` by the default metaclass ``type``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NamedTuple` is not intended to provide more than a type-checked namedtuple. The `NamedTupleMeta` [explicitly prohibits](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.3/Lib/typing.py#L1339) overwriting `__new__`, `__init__` and a few others. Your only chance is to change how `NamedTuple` works.

---

The protection against overwriting `__new__` is not protected itself. This allows you to monkey patch it in various ways.

---

You can remove `__new__` from the protected names.

```
import typing
typing._prohibited = typing._prohibited[1:]
```

This allows you to directly overwrite `__new__` in your class.
Note that this will affect *all* `NamedTuple` subtypes.

---

You can derive a new metaclass that does not protect `__new__`, and use this for your `NamedTuple` instances:

```
class NamedTupleUnprotectedMeta(typing.NamedTupleMeta):
    def __new__(cls, typename, bases, ns):
        ...
        # copy verbatim from NamedTupleMeta
        ...
        # update from user namespace without protection
        for key in ns:
            if key not in typing._special and key not in nm_tpl._fields:
                setattr(nm_tpl, key, ns[key])
        return nm_tpl


class Person(NamedTuple, metaclass=NamedTupleUnprotectedMeta):
    ...
```

This allows you to directly overwrite `__new__` in your class, without affecting other subtypes of `NamedTuple`. Note that you could also have your metaclass add a custom `new` that invokes the defaults set in the class body.

---

Note that `NamedTupleMeta` also ignores the `bases`, so you cannot use mixins and the like either. Any extensive changes require rewriting `NamedTupleMeta` first.

---

If you only need a storage-class with defaults, the [`dataclasses` standard library package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) and the [`attrs` third-party package](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/index.html) provide declarations matching what you describe:

```
@attr.s(auto_attribs=True)
class Person:
    name: str
    children: List['Person'] = attr.Factory(list)
```

Both packages support freezing, which is similar to the immutability of tuples.